# Java : does regex pattern matcher have a size limit?

Tags: java

My pattern is OR-like : "word1|word2|word3"
I have approximately 800 words.

Can it be a problem ?

Comment: If all you're trying to do is to find whether your input string matches one out of a list of strings, there are probably better approaches than an enormous regex.

Comment: this is probably very nice example of regex misuse.

Comment: Yes it can be a performance problem, and a problem is one word is a prefix of another word.

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

You're only limited by memory and sanity. :)

Comment: @arshajii Brand of cat food?

Comment: The point is, an 800-word regex like the one the OP is describing indicates a serious design flaw. Your answer implies that everything is just fine.

Comment: insanity is not usually considered just fine

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using the [Aho–Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) string searching algorithm. It would be much more efficient than a regex, since it's linear and optimized for your problem.
It's also a way to pay respect to our fellows from 1975 !

In particular, there is this Java [implementation](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/java/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Why should it be? No, probably not.

A regexp with 800 words indicates a design problem somewhere, I would say. Why and what for do you need 800 words?

Comment: +1 for design problem. I'd suggest to the op to edit this question providing more detail.

Comment: I am in fact counting the occurrences of a list of 800 words in a corpus. Is there any better way to do it rather than with a regex ?

Comment: Yes, using `HashMap<String, Integer>`. Split the text on non-words (regex `\W` if I am not mistaken), which will give you an array of `String`s. Go through each element of that array. If the hash map contains the word, increase the value by 1; if not - insert the word as a key and put 1 as value. This should be more efficient, but that is only my opinion.