# Comparing 2 text files of different locale in java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to compare 2 files out of which, one is plain text(non-english) and other is glossary in key value pair. They look similar to this:

**Japanese Text file:**

```
わたしのなまえはしんです。
ソフトウェアインギネアとしてはたらいています.
```

**En-Jp properties file:**

```
as:と
software:ソフトウェア
me:わたしを
name:なまえ
I:わたしは
working:はたらいています。
...
```

I am trying to compare these 2 files content wise with below code:

```
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String localtext;
        String glossarytext;
        File dictionary = new File("./src/main/resources/ZN_EN_Test.txt"); 
       Scanner dictScanner = new Scanner(dictionary); 
       File list = new File("./src/main/resources/ZN_JP_Test.txt");
      try
        {
          while(dictScanner.hasNextLine()){

            glossarytext=dictScanner.nextLine();

                try (Scanner listScanner = new Scanner(list);){
                    while(listScanner.hasNextLine()){
                       localtext=listScanner.nextLine();

                        if(glossarytext.contains(localtext))
                        System.out.println(localtext);

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Problem here is, since the Japanese text do not have space in between 2 words, scanner seems to be failing to pass `contains` condition. The same program runs successfully if I arrange words something like below:

```
わたしの
なまえ
は
しん
です。
```

How should I make it work to find the matching contents without formatting Japanese text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to reformulate the question: you have a plain text with no delimiter, and a dictionary (possible more words in dictionary than in text ?), and you want to know if the plain text is a concatenation of the dictionary words - true or false -.

Scanner is more intended to work with delimiter. And you dont have.

Better use Matcher.

1 Then you have to construct a regex, with all of your dictionary words (word1 | word2 | word3 | ....) *

2 and you match

If you have too many words in dictionary, see this: [Java : does regex pattern matcher have a size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358387/java-does-regex-pattern-matcher-have-a-size-limit)

there is also link to Aho–Corasick algorithm

Remark 1: if you want to get the decomposition, see this:
[Create array of regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020384/create-array-of-regex-matches)

Remark 2: the response can be ambiguious, depends on your words (if you have AA, BB, and AABB in your dictionary - I dont know japanese).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. `Matchers` are helpful, as I only want to see if particular pattern exists or not. I really don't want to extract matched pattern. But all above mentioned remarks and references are really helpful.